# How do I create a timed scheduler in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, timer

I would like to create a relatively simple timed event scheduling function in an MVC website for application functions, not necessarily for users at this time, but could be in the future.  My current desire is to use the schedule to cause specific changes to the website based on timed events. The general idea is shown below at the end of the post.

I first investigated Quartz for asp.net because it was recommended on other posts, but the advice in that open source package specifically recommended not using it in an embedded mode.  I don't think I can add it as a service to the server where the MVC site is hosted.

Although I'm familiar with the concept of multi-threading, I am not experienced with it.  Is running the Timer Process below on a background thread a good solution, or should I be looking at something else?  I assumed the Timer Process would simply execute forever, comparing the schedule against the system clock and cause the required event code to run when the time trigger occurs.

If threading is a bad idea please advise where I should look.  If threading is the right idea, any suggestions or warnings would be appreciated.  I am reading up on threading at this time.

I have several specific questions:

```
1) Should the individual event code run on the same thread, or does it matter? 
2) How do I handle the problem others have suggested occurs if 'IIS kills the thread' or the 'app pool is recycled'.
3) Is it a wrong idea that I send some message to the MVC site that triggers the Timer Process to overcome the issues in #2 above?
4) Is there a way to force a page to automatically refresh with a new display when the timer event occurs?  That doesn't seem to be the way asp.net MVC normally works.
```

Finally, this sounded like a problem that others have probably resolved and reduced to an open source solution for asp.net MVC. As I look through Nu-Get there are a few that seem to describe this problem, but they have very few downloads.  Any recommendations along this route?

[image]

Comment: For Asp.NET Core, look into [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: IMHO, some `cron` job or even a _separate_ Windows Scheduler job - essentially, _outside/separate_ of/from the web application, for the reasons you already researched. Unsure what you mean by "configuration changes" - typically those will trigger an app restart.

Comment: @EdSF I'm assuming you are referring to "refresh with a new configuration" - poor choice of words on my part - I'll correct it.  Intended to ask how to force a page refresh.  For ex, change a displayed picture based on the time of day.  I'm trying to understand how to force a page to re-display if some artifact on the page is supposed to change at a given time, which is the next task I have to accomplish after I understand how to get a reliable timer event to occur.  Thanks for the suggestion to accomplish timing outside of the MVC app.

Comment: @Alan - a "page refresh" is an event by some client/end user. What value would a timed process (with no user) have? If you're saying "reset"/"invalidate" some cached resource (image), then perhaps that's where you should be looking(?). If it's just some dynamic display based on some logical evaluation, then that too, doesn't sound like it needs some extra "job"?

Comment: @EdSF I am considering a web page displayed on a monitor where a user isn't necessarily actively interacting with the website.  Over time the display needs to change based on some particular timing. If the user were to take an action that resulted in a new page display, the display would include the updated content, but I want the content to update whether or not the user takes any action.  The timed event is the trigger that determines when the webpage display should have a different set of content.

Comment: @Alan then all of that is client side (Javascript) - you want the trigger on the client (polling). You can also look into [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/real-time)

Comment: @EdSF I see.  I believe you have pointed me to where I need to go.  I'd like to confirm I'm getting this correctly: What I'm trying to do is not solved by the server 'pushing' content, but rather by the client 'polling' for new content.  Is that a generally correct understanding?

Comment: @Alan - depends on what you want - server side push and/or client side polling. Use what fits for your use case/easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case will be good to use Hangfire. You can configure like parallel server and create different jobs with different schedule.

For NetCore app:

```
app.UseHangfireServer();
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", options);

// Process notifications every 6 hours
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<B2CEngineNotifications>(jobEngine =>  jobEngine.SendBillingNotifications(), "0 */6 * * *");
```

In this case each job works in his own thread.

**1) Should the individual event code run on the same thread, or does it matter?**
It depends what type of events do you expect. If they are not depended, you can do it in separate threads.

**How do I handle the problem others have suggested occurs if 'IIS kills the thread' or the 'app pool is recycled'.**
Hangfire will create in your DB some tables. If you will terminate process, on next start it get all data from db and start execute events on scedule.

**Is it a wrong idea that I send some message to the MVC site that triggers the Timer Process to overcome the issues in #2 above?**
Hangfire has his own interface to manage jobs. Or you need to have a option to start event from your MVC app? You can do it from MVC just change db values. And hangfire will start job.

**Is there a way to force a page to automatically refresh with a new display when the timer event occurs?  That doesn't seem to be the way asp.net MVC normally works.**
In this case you need to use AJAX to have "live" connection with server and "ask" is something changed or not.

Comment: I followed your advice to try hangfire, thanks.  I have been successful getting it up and running, but only according to the simple tutorial.  All I'm doing is logging messages.  I'd like to now understand how I move on to cause actionable code to execute.  Whether it's a batch file, which I won't likely use anytime soon, or a re-entry into MVC code.  It's just not obvious to me from what I've read how to do that.  I will likely have to make another SO post to ask about that, but thought I would ask you first in these comments if case you have a link to something that might help.

Comment: Hi @Alan.
If I understand correctly you have some class in MVC which one you want to start. You can Create new class
`public class B2CEngineNotifications : IEngine
{
public void DoSomething()
{
//call your class which you injected in constructor
}
}` or could you please describe a little bit more about "actionable code to execute"

Comment: After I posted, as often is the case, upon reflection it came to me what is going on in the sample hangfire MVC project on GitHub and I was able to schedule a job.  I added in Startup.vb the line:  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(Sub() HomeController.Event1(), Cron.Minutely).  It took me a while to get help translating the C# into VB.net.  Thank you so much for all your help.  On to the next issue...